# directx texture dimensions

Tags: directx, textures, direct3d, dimensions

so I've discovered that my graphics card automatically resizes textures to powers of 2, which isn't usually a problem but I need to render only a portion of my texture and in doing so, must have the dimensions it has been resized to...

ex:
I load a picture that is 370x300 pixels into my texture and try to draw it with a specific source rectangle

```
RECT test;
    test.left = 0;
    test.top = 0;
    test.right = 370;
    test.bottom = 300;

    lpSpriteHandler->Draw(
        lpTexture,
        &test,          // srcRect
        NULL,           // center
        NULL,            // position
        D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255)
        );
```

but since the texture has been automatically resized (in this case) to 512x512, I see only a portion of my original texture.

The question is, 
is there a function or something I can call to find the dimensions of my texture?
(I've tried googling this but always get some weird crap about Objects and HSL or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get file information by using this call:

```
D3DXIMAGE_INFO info;
D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(file_name, &info);
```

Though, knowing the original texture size you'll still get it resized on load. This will obviously affect texture quality. Texture resizing is not a big deal when you apply it on mesh (it will get resized anyway) but for drawing sprites this could be a concern. To workaround this I could suggest creating a surface, loading it via `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile` and then copying it to a "pow2" sized texture.

And an offtopic: are you definitely sure about your card capabilities? May be in fact your card **do** support arbitrary texture sizes but you use `D3DXCreateTextureFromFile()` which by deafult enforces pow2 sizes. To avoid this try using extended version of this routine:

```
D3DTexture* texture;
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(
    device, file_name, D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2, D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0,
    D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL,
    &texture);
```

If your hardware suppors non-pow2 textures you'll get your file loaded as it is. If hardware is not able to handle it than method will fail.