# Placing an image on a window while controlling its size - directX, c++

Tags: image, textures, direct3d, image-size

*All code is pseudo*

I have an image sized 1024 x 768.

It is a jpg

I have a window sized 1024 x 768.

I create a sprite, get a texture for it, then draw it to the screen.

for example:

```
D3DXCreateSprite( gfx.d3dDevice, &sprite );
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile( gfx.d3dDevice, _fileName, &gTexture );
....
pos.x = 0.0f;
pos.y = 0.0f;
pos.z = 0.0f;
sprite->Draw( scenes[ 0 ]->backgroundImage->gTexture, NULL, NULL, &pos, 0xFFFFFFFF );
```

When it comes out on to the screen, the picture is warped and does not look how it should:

[image]

My question would be:

How do I control the size of the output of the image when none of the texture, sprite or draw functions seem to have functionality for it..?

I thought maybe it was something to do with Rect but that just clips images //shrugs//

May be this I need to use:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887494.aspx
- [directx texture dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942959/directx-texture-dimensions?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

```
result = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx( 
    gfx.d3dDevice, 
    _fileName, 
    1024, 
    768, 
    D3DX_DEFAULT, 
    0, 
    D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, 
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED, 
    D3DX_DEFAULT, 
    D3DX_DEFAULT, 
    0, 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    &gTexture 
);
```

D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx allows a texture to be created without any size warping:

- this was helpful: [directx texture dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942959/directx-texture-dimensions?rq=1)
- and this was extremely helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms887494.aspx